# Embed html code inside odoo form

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

How embed e.g youtube in custom module in odoo 9?

After open link from menu show youtube video in form.

Any simple solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a view in Odoo, there are some predefined tags that will be treated differently by Odoo when the parsing takes place. For example `<form>`, `<tree>` etc. **The rest of the tags will be rendered as simple HTML tags**. That means that you can write HTML code inside the formview that will be rendered to your client.

Insert the video in the view as you would insert it on a simple HTML page and it should be rendered correctly, some changes might be needed because Odoo injects some of its own code on the parsing process.

Comment: does this mean I can also use the script tag to execute javascript?

Answer (score 3):

You can use  in the form view.

and use simple the way iframe is embeded. You can consider the example below -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
    <form string="Embedded Webpage" version="7.0" edit="false" create="false"> 
        <div style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0; width:100%; height:100%;"> 
          <iframe src="http://www.playkeepout.com/" width="100%" height="100%" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" style="border-width:0px;"></iframe> 

        </div> 
    </form>
```

Comment: Hello Shikhar S,  Above code is code for .xml view? How define menu link and after click open form with iframe?